# How to mock window object's properties and functions in Angular CLI v5

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I have added new function to window object in ngOnInit method and wanted to write test cases for that function but don't know how to mock window object and how to cover following function in test coverage.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 (<any>window).validateLogoutService=function(): any{
    window.location.href=hostURL;
  };
};
```

Need to cover test cases for validateLogoutService.